# Does more information ALWAYS increase accuracy of inference?

Tags: probability

I'm curious from a probability theory perspective if more information always increases accuracy of inference? So just an example of "more information" let's say I have to infer someone's name given only the first 3 characters and knowing it's 5 characters long, let's say "Dav" are the first 3 letters. "More information" in this case would be I also know that the 5th character is "d" so I now have "Dav_d." This is just an example, but I'm wondering if generally more information gives a tighter bound on the probabilistic inference one can make?

Comment: I think the additional information needs to fit the problem too. For example, if you want to know the name of a person and know it starts with "Dav". Then, the additional information, that the persons favourite color is "red" does not help you in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure what "information" refers to here.  If, in your situation, I tell you that my lucky number is $14$, that wouldn't appear to help you in your quest.  You could of course require that the new information be "relevant" to the problem, but I fear that you'll end up in a tautology...where "relevant" is defined as "increasing the accuracy of the inference" or something like that.

Comment: It depends on what is being inferred. If two many predictor variables are present then overfitting in regression can occur. If we are trying to infer a probability distribution for the data, then yes, we expect more data to help the distribution to converge to what it actually is (although true convergence in the mathematical sense may not occur in the wild, so we have good enough estimates.)

Comment: Insofar as the phrasing of your question is open to interpretation, it is not well defined.  It is obviously true that the set "Dav\*" is larger than the set "Dav\*d\*", at least for names up to any given finite length.  But the set of inference algorithms is not well defined - although you can come up with some common sense constraints on allowed inference algorithms for a particular set of problems, in which case you've answered your own question, c.f. @lulu .

Comment: What does "increase" mean here?  Does it mean "strictly increase" or does it mean "does not decrease"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, it depends on what exactly you mean. In the following, I'll assume that you mean Bayesian inference. As has been noted in a comment, for other ways of trying to use information, such as interpolating polynomials, things may get worse.

If you're thinking of the accuracy of individual predictions, the answer is no. For instance, say you want to know whether I rolled an even number on a standard die. You ask me whether I rolled a Fibonacci number, and I say “yes” because I rolled a $2$. Before you asked, you assigned probability $\frac12$ to the event that I rolled an even number. After you asked, since the Fibonacci numbers on a die are $1$, $2$, $3$ and $5$, you assign probability $\frac14\lt\frac12$ to  the event that I rolled an even number, even though it in fact occurred. Thus the new information has lowered the accuracy of your prediction.

However, if you ask whether new information will increase the accuracy of your predictions *on average*, the answer is: perhaps not increase (it might be irrelevant), but also not decrease, in a certain sense.

The inaccuracy of your prediction can be measured by the entropy of the relevant distribution. The entropy can be viewed as the expected information gained when sampling from the distribution, but it can also be viewed as follows: Say you state your beliefs $q_i$ for how likely each event $i$ is, when in fact the probabilities are $p_i$. We can assess the accuracy of your beliefs by the function

$$
f(\{q_i\})=\sum_ip_i\ln q_i\;,
$$

which is the expected value of $\ln q_i$ and is maximized for $q_i=p_i$. Thus the negative entropy $\sum_ip_i\ln p_i$ is the maximum value of this function that you can reach by assigning the correct probabilities $p_i$.

Now say we’re only interesting in the accuracy of your prediction of an event $E$ (say, that I roll an even number), and that there is also an event $A$ that could give you information (say, that I roll a Fibonacci number), but we’re not interested in your prediction of it. Without the information from $A$, the accuracy of your prediction of $E$ is

$$
p(E)\ln p(E)+p(\overline E)\ln p(\overline E)\;.
$$

Then you ask me whether $A$ occurred. Say it occurred (as in the example above). Now the accuracy of your prediction of $E$ is

\begin{eqnarray}
p(E\mid A)\ln p(E\mid A)+p(\overline E\mid A)\ln p(\overline E\mid A)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

This may be higher or lower than the accuracy of your previous prediction.  (For more on this, see also my answer to [Entropy of a race](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3172904).) But if it’s lower, it’s the occurrence of $A$ that lowers it, not your learning about this occurrence. If $A$ in fact occurred but you don’t know it and stick with your probabilities $p(E)$ and $p(\overline E)$, then your accuracy will be

$$
p(E\mid A)\ln p(E)+p(\overline E\mid A)\ln p(\overline E)\;,
$$

which is even lower (since, as we saw above, the correct probabilities maximize the accuracy function).

Morever, if we take the expected value over both possibilities (that $A$ occurred or didn't occur) the expected value of the logarithms of the probabilities you assign is

$$
p(A\cap E)\ln p(E\mid A)+p(A\cap\overline E)\ln p(\overline E\mid A)+p(\overline A\cap E)\ln p(E\mid\overline A)+p(\overline A\cap\overline E)\ln p(\overline E\mid\overline A)\\
=p(A\cap E)\ln p(A\cap E)+p(A\cap\overline E)\ln p(A\cap\overline E)+p(\overline A\cap E)\ln p(\overline A\cap E)+p(\overline A\cap\overline E)\ln p(\overline A\cap\overline E)\\-(p(A)\ln p(A)+p(\overline A\ln p(\overline A))\;.
$$

This is the negative entropy of the joint distribution of $A$ and $E$ minus the negative entropy of the distribution of $A$. Your original accuracy was the negative entropy of the distribution of $E$. Since the entropy of the joint distribution is minimized if the two events are independent, and in that case is the sum of the entropies of their marginal distributions, it follows that this expected accuracy is equal to your original accuracy if $A$ and $E$ are independent, and higher if they aren’t.

In this sense, if you learn new information, the accuracy of your predictions either stays the same (if the new information is irrelevant, that is, independent of what you’re trying to predict) or increases.